# Continuous Deployment in Cloud

Tags: sql-server, continuous-deployment, continuous

I am assinged for the task of Continuous deployment from development server to production server.

In my development server all the database objects will be created under the 'DBO' Schema. But in Production server based on every Tenants company list differenet SCHEMAS will be there.

for E.g  in my development server if a tablename is created like

```
   dbo.ABC
   dbo.XYZ
```

And while i creating a tenant(Omkar---db) (Sarkur,Mathur--- schemas), the database objects will be like

Sarkur.ABC, sarkur.XYZ
Mathur.ABC, Mathur.XYZ

Now, i have to compare these two databases to check whether any changes in structure of the database objects, addition / deletion of database objects. If so that changes has tobe synchronized in the production database.

If anyone know that how to compare these two different schemas object, pls let me know..

Comment: Which db server you are using?

Comment: as well as i tried with DBDacfx framework concept

Answer (score 0):

1 option that I know is looking suitable

**Flyway  :**

1. It is Easy to setup, simple to master. Flyway let's you regain control of your database migrations with pleasure and plain sql.
2. Solves only one problem and solves it well. Flyway migrates your database, so you don't have to worry about it anymore.
3. Made for continuous delivery. Let Flyway migrate your database on application startup. Releases have never been this easy.

Big Plus **It's Open Source framework!**

http://flywaydb.org/